# validate sql query in non paremetrized sql query for security issues

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-injection

Can someone share any non parametrized sql query validation to prevent injection attacks. I am using a vendor Rhino JS API within an applet to pass the query and I have to use infamous `+""+` concats to build my query dynamically. Though my function will only be used by developers with data not directly from users, I want to add some basic validations. I do seem some escaping and white listing methods listed [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) but has someone implemented these and share few thoughts. Its for SQL server.

Comment: As long as you are going to take input and build up a string to execute you potentially have the vulnerability. No amount of white listing or replace functions can prevent all attempts at sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft's developer network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Never build Transact-SQL statements directly from user input.

Instead use type-safe parameters.